# How is fuel distributed in multi engine rocket stages?

Tags: falcon-9, fuel, engineering, electron, centaur

How is fuel distributed evenly to multi-engine rockets like the Falcon 9, Electron, or multi-engined Centaurs? I would presume that there is only one main propellant line that goes down the raceway then there is some kind of "splitter"? My fluid dynamics understanding is... limited evidently so if, by any chance you know of any recommended sources that I can read to better understand fluid dynamics in the engineering setting that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out how the LOX lines ran through the fuel tank on the Saturn V first stage. I always liked that. http://heroicrelics.org/info/s-ic/s-ic-general.html

Comment: The first stage of the Saturn V used one oxygen line per engine, so five lines altogether. There was no splitter to avoid interactions of the five oxygen pumps sucking from the same line. For fuel there were two lines per engine.

Comment: Even though it's a joke that rocket science is just plumbing, but here this is exactly the area in rocket science that is nothing but high performance plumbing, just like other industries like power plants and nuclear reactors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer (for Centaur and Saturn 1-B)

The H2 line emerges from the boost pump, which is mounted at one side of the base of the H2 tank.  The line then wraps around the O2 tank and splits near its base to reach both engines.

The O2 line emerges from its boost pump which is located in the center base of the O2 tank. The line splits almost immediately and leads to both engines.

[image]

[Schematic](https://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Boosters/Centaur/D-1T_Propellant_Feed.gif) from Titan/Centaur T/C-1 Post Flight Evaluation Report (Colorized by me)

Here's an interesting (to me anyway) example from the Saturn 1-B. This stage had parallel tanks, not tandem, so all the drain points were near the bottom of the stage. With 8 engines there was a lot of plumbing.

[image]

Schematic from *H-1C-D Engine Manual* which I'm not seeing online ATM. Colorized by me.

Comment: Thank you! Great colorizations!